# "xda" and other stuff keep being typed on my internal PS/2 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bios, ps2, ps2-keyboard, bug

My internal PS/2 laptop keyboard keeps typing stuff i don't know why. Here's a sample:

``````
/*+-~~xda<`/*+-~~xda</*xd/*+-~~/*+-~~xda/*+-~~xda<`/*+-~~xda<`<`````////////////////////////////////*+-~~xda<`
``````

And another sample:

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
/*+-~~xda<`/*+-~~xda<`/*+-~~xda</*+-~~xda<`````````/*+-~~xda<`/*+-~~xda<```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

At first I had the gut feel that it was because I installed some malware. So I tried re-installing my Windows 10. Unfortunately, the keyboard typing mishap is still happening. I also tried installing Linux but the typing keeps on happening.

After a few readings, I found out this thing called EFI that somehow replaced BIOS functions and is apparently commonly being exploited.

So, I have a few questions:

1. Could there be a possible reason why the keyboard keeps typing "xda" specifically?
2. Could the problem be due to a short circuit in the PS/2 keyboard?
3. Which of the following has more likely happened: (a) EFI-based malware (b) PS/2 keyboard short circuit (c) keyboard driver problem
4. Are the stock PS/2 keyboard drivers of Windows 10 and Linux essentially the same?
5. Do standard PS/2 keyboard drivers have eccentricities based on manufacturer (e.g. Acer vs Asus vs Steelseries)?
6. How can Linux command "dmidecode" be able to give me important details regarding what's wrong? (What details should I look for?)
7. Would it be possible to increase the electronic threshold for my keyboard so that only actual presses will get detected?

Comment: There are some very basic tests you can perform to rule some things out. It's almost certainly not a driver or software issue if the problem exists on both Windows and Linux. Have you tried the keyboard on another PC? Have you tried another keyboard on this PC? In all likelihood it's a hardware issue with the keyboard itself, although there could be an error with the motherboard's PS2 port.

Comment: the usb keyboard is working but i haven't tried the ps2 keyboard on another PC though. i'm using a laptop

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem to me, most likely a dirty keyboard membrane/circuit. If you can hook up a USB keyboard, and do not experience the same issue that happens with your laptop's keyboard, then the laptop keyboard is the most likely the cause of the problem. Try carefully disassembling and cleaning the laptop keyboard. It is not a malware.